# Is it possible to use the Projection_traits_xy_3 adapter with the "2D Polyline Simplification" package to simplify 2.5D polylines with CGAL?

Tags: cgal

I need to simplify a set of 2.5D polylines. Specifically, 3D polylines that do not overlap in the XY plane.

I tried to use the Projection_traits_xy_3 adapter with the "2D Polyline Simplification" package from CGAL, but I have compilation errors when calling the function CGAL::Polyline_simplification_2::simplify, after building the triangulation.

If what I'm trying to do is currently possible to do with CGAL, please someone can show me the basic example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out.  I added the point/segment distance to `Projection_traits_xy_3` and added an example in this [pull request](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3806).